# angular-file-upload a file without file information in the result

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angular-file-upload

I am using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) to upload files to my Sharepoint web. The files upload fine with the REST API, but when I open the file, I don't want the "header" and "footer" to be in the form data. for example, in a .png file, I don't want to see this:

```
-----------------------------7df1e925b0384
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Tutorial1.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

before

```
‰PNG

IHDR  X     r5˜   bKGD ÿ ÿ ÿ ½§“     pHYs     šœ   tIMEß
;×Þ¯   iTXtComment     Created with GIMPd.e    IDATxÚìÝ{\UeÂ÷ÿ¯¬FØ¡†¨4ÆIMCÆ¡G;‰£¤£wŒf“¥=S£Ä¯É;Sµ[ÍÉy’Ü–Þc
Ž¤Žh'BHn‡a°ÑTNZ¨Hê–äà”VÃï..................
```

and I would also like to get rid of this at the end:

```
-----------------------------7df1e925b0384--
```

Is there any way to do this through the angular-file-upload usage? I am referencing these files (and a similar scenario with html views) in my code and the content is being messed up by these pieces of extra info.

Any help or alternative ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I should have read the documentation more carefully, but what I needed to do was use the $upload.http() function instead of the $upload.upload() function. I then defined things like content-type in the headers, and the file body is clean. [This](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/issues/88) is what I followed in the end.